# Sound disappeared after playing for couple hours on iPhone14 (WebAudio API)

Tags: ios, iphone, game-development, web-audio-api

The HTML5 game I developed uses the WebAudio API to play sound effects,
and the sound played successfully at first.

However, after playing for couple hours, the sound started to have some noise, then it disappeared completely, and the phone began overhearing.

After the sound disappeared, I tried two things:

1. Opening the game on another tab, and the sound played successfully.
2. Reloading the tab, and the sound played successfully too.

So, I'm wondering if there is any restriction of the WebAudio API on iOS that could be causing this issue?

The phone I used for testing is the iPhone14, and its iOS version is 16.6.